# Two WHERE & COUNT in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get two summations in the same query based on different criteria. Both criteria operate on the same column.
Is there a way to do this?

I can best explain this with an example:

> Table : 
>   salary_survey_result
>
> Columns:
>   industry,
>   location,
>   position,
>   salary

Effectively I want to combine the following two queries:

```
SELECT industry, location, count(*) as MORE_THAN_SIX_FIGURE   
FROM salary_survey_result  
WHERE salary > 100000  
GROUP BY industry, location
```

and

```
SELECT industry, location, count(*) as MORE_THAN_FIVE_FIGURE  
FROM salary_survey_result  
WHERE salary > 10000  
GROUP BY industry, location
```

So the result is something like this:
    `industry    location    MORE_THAN_FIVE_FIGURE      MORE_THAN_SIX_FIGURE`

---

```
Healthcare    NY               45                      10  
Healthcare    MN               35                       6   
InfoTech      NY               50                      19
InfoTech      MN               40                      12
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT industry, 
       location, 
       sum( case when salary >= 10000 then 1 else 0 end) as MORE_THAN_FIVE_FIGURE,
       sum( case when salary >= 100000 then 1 else 0 end) as MORE_THAN_SIX_FIGURE
  FROM salary_survey_result  
  WHERE salary >= 10000  
  GROUP BY industry, location
```

The `WHERE salary >= 10000` clause isn't necessary for the results.  It may improve performance if there is an index on `SALARY` and most salary values are less than 10000.  Note that I'm also assuming that you meant `>=` rather than `>` since a salary of 10,000 is a five figure salary.

Comment: +1 `having sum( case when salary >= 10000 then 1 else 0 end) > 0`

Comment: As a matter of personal preference, I switched from using sum like this to `count(when salary > 100000 then 1 else null end)` to make it clear that the result is a count of something.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT industry, location, count(*) as MORE_THAN_FIVE_FIGURE ,sum(salary > 100000) as MORE_THAN_SIX_FIGURE
FROM salary_survey_result  
WHERE salary > 10000  
GROUP BY industry, location
```

Comment: `sum(salary > 100000)` isn't valid syntax.